# how to remove tweets link inside mongo db

Tags: mongodb

I have a set of tweets data in MongoDB. all tweets contain some bad expression like //,? or links. for example:

`"text": "We\\'re through one end in  Australia vs.  Scotland in the GOLD medal match of men\\'s triples!   Get around the action  https:12345567   #GC2018 #ShareTheDream https`

How can I replace (remove) them? I tried to use remove() function but removing it is not good because it will remove the whole text. I just want to remove the bad words, but leave the text as it is

Answer (score 1):

For special characters use `str.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g, "");`.

Or you can specifiy each char you wish to remove `string.replace(/[&\/\\#,+()$~%.'":*?<>{}]/g, '');`

For URL's `b = url.replace(/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+/g, '');`

Pay attention to escape character '\'.

Comment: Would mind explaining how to write this in mongo query format?  I have a collection called data. So is it  db.data.replace()  ? Sorry to ask in details but I am trying to do it in MongoDB

Comment: [2 queries approach] What you have to do is find the data made changes in it and save it again. Give it a try, see if you got the corrected result. If still, you find it difficult, I will help you with the query. One question are you using some script or you are doing it on shell itself?

Comment: Thank you. I actually tried both:The first one in the shell is : db.genders.find().forEach(function(doc) {
  doc.description = doc.description.replace(/https\\/g, ''); 
  db.test.save(doc);
});   And I am trying to write a python script as well

Comment: db.gender_m.find().forEach(function(doc) {
  doc.description = doc.description.replace(/(?:https?|ftp):\/\/[\n\S]+/g, ''); 
  db.text.save(doc);
});   This seems working> thak you so much !